# How to properly move mysql dumps between hosts

Tags: mysql, migration

One would thing that it will be as easy as

```
mysqldump -u root -p -QqeR --add-drop-table --all-databases | bzip2 -v9 - > blabla.sql.bz2
```

and then import on the other side, but in real world that's often not the case.

For example on the new host I have control panel that has few users in mysql db already.
I would like to keep those and also add the ones from the mysql db on the old host. The conflicts should not be overwritten but keept as they are.
I figured that would be the easier way to have all the sites works without changing DB users and passwords and also have the control panel and other scripts on the new hosts keep doing their jobs without changes.
Well how to do that though?

Can you merge stuff? Or one would approach it via phpmyadmin easier?

Comment: Have you considered [setting the instances up as a cluster](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17730/724)?

Comment: That's not relevant to this case at all. It's a simple migration.

Comment: Just exclude the `mysql` database?

Comment: It's clearly stated that users should be kept.
I found the solution in the meantime. 
One should export all from  USERS and DB tables, without the first few lines in the USERS table where the root and other system passwords are.
The import that on the fresh mysql DB on the new place.